# Get Javascript nested array object values

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object

I have this Javascript object

```
var output = { 
   "_resolved": true, 
   "_result": [ { 
                   "title": "Pencil", 
                   "quantity": 1, 
                   "objectId": "HknL2ZAspb" 
              } ] 
}
```

When I try to get the value of title like this:

```
output._result[0].title
```

it returns undefined.

However

```
output._result[0]
```

correctly returns

```
{ "title": "Pencil", "quantity": 1, "objectId": "HknL2ZAspb" }
```

Any idea why `output._result[0].title` returns undefined?
I also tried `output["_result"][0]["title"]` but it returns undefined too.

```
var output = { 
   "_resolved": true, 
   "_result": [ { 
                   "title": "Pencil", 
                   "quantity": 1, 
                   "objectId": "HknL2ZAspb" 
              } ] 
}

console.log(output._result[0].title);
```

Serverside code (Node):

```
const productsQuery = new Parse.Query(ProductTable);

output = productsQuery.get('HknL2ZAspb');   //objectID

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send(JSON.stringify(output["_result"][0]["title"])))
```

Note the Query and other code is just fine. As output returns the exact object.

Comment: `output._result[0].title` works correctly with the data you provided. You must have a typo in your code.

Comment: I can't reproduce this at all, `output._result[0]` works fine and so does `output["_result"][0]["title"]`. Are you sure that `output._result[0]` returns the json and not a string?

Comment: Show your code related to your post.

Comment: it is working , i have included snippet on your question , must be something else

Comment: I'm using node.js
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send(JSON.stringify(output["_result"][0]["title"]))

Comment: @Daman please add full code of app.get handler body

Comment: Jut edited the question with code.

Comment: Isn't the parse query asynchronous?

Comment: @SachiTekina console.log(output._result[0].title); throws an error.
           TypeError: Cannot read property 0 ^of undefined

Comment: @Daman If you do `typeof output._result[0]`, what does it return?

Comment: can You explain what is Parse object ? Is data hardcoded and productsQuery.get return the object from that hardcoded data?

Comment: @pfg it says - object

Comment: @Daman Another way to check this, what does `JSON.stringify(output._result[0])` return? I have no idea what's going on here

Comment: @Daman, pfg, guys what about making video sharing using appear in and checking what happens?  link: http://appear.in/daman   I'm already there, let's see

Comment: or move this to chat

Comment: Are you using [parse](http://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/)?

Comment: @Mark_M yes sir, Parse Server

Comment: Isn't `parse.get()` asynchronous?

Comment: @Mark_M Even this returns the same
productsQuery.first({
    success: function (results) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(results.title));
    }
});

Comment: @Daman I think You're missing somethings or You don't want to share with us Your code as is, even You don't want to collaborate in appear.in to make us help You. So what community can respond You? Simply to say: You're using async stuff wrong. And `output = productsQuery.get('HknL2ZAspb')` returns a field of returned object, inc Your case to get the title: `const title = productsQuery.get('title')`  but of course we dont' have full code what Your have

Answer (score 1):

Since You're using Parse and it's asynchronous thing.

From examples in [official documentation](http://docs.parseplatform.org/parse-server/guide/) I can give working example:

```
const ProductTable = 'products';

app.get('/products/:id', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const productId = req.params.id;
    const query = (new Parse.Query(ProductTable))
                    .equalTo('objectId', productId);
    const result = await query.find();

    if (result[0]) {
      return res.status(200).send(result[0]);
    }
    res.status(404).send({});
  }
  catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send(error);
  }
});
```

Use it like: http://127.0.0.1:3000/products/HknL2ZAspb

Comment: I do. because when i output
output._result
it does output an Object

Comment: Why does everything return the right values though? Could all the things we've tried been called later after everything has been downloaded?

Comment: @pfg Daman was not giving whole code, + I did not found any mention of .get to query object. Maybe it's some abstraction over Parse class. So I've just wrote proper example depending on official manual. In another hand result and resolved may be special fields of custom promise object that is being logged to console or stringified on demand.